# Highlighting most recent point in time slider playback using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, timeslider

I am trying to put together a video where spatial points from an animal are displayed.  However, many of these points are on top of other points and it is easy to lose track of what is happening.

Is there a way to highlight or otherwise change/draw attention to the most recent point being visualized on the map as the time slider plays?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) 10.6.

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.6.  I have not been able to find any information on highlighting the most recent point being displayed using the time slider.  I have checked here and  the arcgis.com help pages specifically and have searched google for other answers.  I have not found anything that relates to what I am looking for.  There does not seem to be a way to address this within the symbology nor the time panes of the point layer's properties.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional clarifications/information.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similiar a while ago. I used two time data set. One just showing the latest point and one showing all the points up to the latest. Then I could use different colors and make the newest point stand out. (I do not use arc these days, so I cannot give any more details)